# JQuery How to select only the current li and not parent

Tags: jquery

How do you select using JQuery the current li and not its parents.

In my sample below, when I hover over a li that has a parent li the 'world' gets displayed on the parent as well as the current li.

I would like to only display the 'world' in the current li.

How do I do this?

style:

```
a.show-anyway
{
  display: block;
}
a.world
{
  display: none;
}
a.active
{
  display: block;
}
```

list items:

```
<ul class="currentlist">
<li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a>
<li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="show-anyway">hello</a><a href="#" class="world">world</a></li>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.currentlist li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to crawl the parents and add/remove the class when entering/leaving the child, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.currentlist li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('a').addClass('active').end()
           .parents().children('a').removeClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $(this).children('a').removeClass('active').end()
           .parents().children('a').addClass('active');
  });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DgGHw/), this crawls the parents and removes the class from their `<a>` children when entering, and restores it when leaving, give the demo a try, I think this is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with eventbubbeling, I played around with it a bit at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt7NE/) and have found some minor improvements.
Try this for the jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.currentlist li').hover(function(evt) {
    $(this).children('a.world').addClass('active');
      evt.stopPropagation()
  }, function(evt) {
    $(this).children('a.world').removeClass('active');
  });
});​
```

Comment: thanks that's what I was trying to achieve. There is one issue though... when you hover over an inner li and move to the outer li it doesn't work. But will work if you coming from the outer li to the inner li.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the nicest of solutions but maybe it will help you find a nicer way.

[jsfiddle.net/s7TaT](http://jsfiddle.net/s7TaT/)

Comment: a nice solution is a working solution - just one thing though. It does a crazy little effect of showing 'world' when you are coming out of a parent li's childres into the next parent li it shows 'world' back at the parent li level

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that if you are hovering a "child li", you are still hovering its parent. So your jQuery function does exactly what you tell it :-)

If you only want to add the 'active' css class to the actual "li", then you must remove the 'active' class from all of its "parent lis".

I would recommend to not add the class to the a tag, but to the li itself (it's actually the hovered li that is active, not only one link on it)

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rCYAm/

Comment: good thought process. Your example also suffers though from the parent li gaining a 'world' when the inner li receives a 'world'